# laravel page expired 419 with @csrf

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

Tried a lot of things from different places in the internet.

Here's dump of session.php configuration:

[image]

I'm using docker.

```yml
    version: '3'
    services:
    
        #PHP Service
        php:
            build:
                context: .
                dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
            container_name: project_php
            extra_hosts:
                - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
            restart: unless-stopped
            tty: true
            working_dir: /var/www
            environment:
                PHP_IDE_CONFIG: 'serverName=project'
            volumes:
                - ./:/var/www/
                - ./docker/php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
                - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
            networks:
                - project-network
    
        #Nginx Service
        nginx:
            image: nginx:alpine
            container_name: project_nginx
            restart: unless-stopped
            tty: true
            ports:
                - "33:80"
            volumes:
                - ./:/var/www/
                - ./docker/nginx/config/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
            networks:
                - project-network
    
        #MySQL Service
        db:
            image: mariadb:latest
            container_name: project_db
            restart: unless-stopped
            tty: true
            ports:
                - "3308:3306"
            volumes:
                - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
            environment:
                MARIADB_DATABASE: project
                MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            networks:
                - project-network
        redis:
            image: redis:alpine
            container_name: project_redis
            restart: unless-stopped
            tty: true
            networks:
                - project-network
    
    #Docker Networks
    networks:
        project-network:
            driver: bridge
```

Form in blade template

```php-template
...
<form class="apply-form needs-validation" novalidate="" method="POST" action="{{route('apply.store')}}">
@csrf
...
```

Not sure what triggered it, when I try and git stash changes, it doesn't work. And yes, I use optimize:clear command to make sure config changes apply to the project. Please, help me figure this out. I'm not sure what else I should do.

.env file

```
APP_NAME=project
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_DOMAIN=localhost:33
APP_URL="http://${APP_DOMAIN}"

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*******

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_STORE=redis

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

**UPD**

composer.json

```json
"require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.54",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "orchid/platform": "^10.23",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1"
    }
```

web.php

```php
Route::get('/apply',    [PageController::class, 'apply'])
    ->name('apply');
Route::post('/apply',    [ApplyController::class, 'create'])
    ->name('apply.store');
```

ApplyController.php

```php
class ApplyController extends Controller
{
    public function create(ApplicationRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $data = $request->validated();
        foreach (Application::OPTIONS as $field => $values) {
            $data[$field] = $values[$data[$field]];
        }
        $application = new Application($data);
        $application->password = Hash::make($data['pass']);
        $application->save();
        Session::put('application_email', $application->email);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Local machine OS: ubuntu

Comment: Are you using MacOS or Windows ? What is your Laravel version ? Can you add your routes file web.php and your method store in your controller ?

Comment: @Jérôme updated the question, added everything you asked. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide relevant files like your `routes file` `routeserviceprovider`, session config file ?

Comment: @Abilogos, I fixed my question. THere's a screen of config array. Route provider is standard I didn't change anything there.

Comment: Do you have APP_KEY set in your .env file?

Comment: @Bazsmagister yes, I tried to regenerate the key, same result.